# Escape variables in command prompt cmd

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-command-prompt, command-line-interface

I set my variable like this:

```
SET Ant="%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Downloads\apache-ant-1.9.0-bin\apache-ant-1.9.0\bin"

:: Set Path variable  
setx PATH "%Ant%" /m
```

Then, the result for the path variable is :

```
C:\Users\Ruben\Downloads\apache-ant-1.9.0-bin\apache-ant-1.9.0\bin
```

As we can see, environnement variables are expanded.

I would like them not to be expanded to set my path variable like this:

```
%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Downloads\apache-ant-1.9.0-bin\apache-ant-1.9.0\bin
```

Is there a way to not expand environnement variables ?

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: @Falcon Momot I've edited the question to improve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This do the trick on my Win7 :

```
SET Ant=^%HOMEDRIVE^%^%HOMEPATH^%\Downloads\apache-ant-1.9.0-bin\apache-ant-1.9.0\bin

setx PATH "%Ant%" /m
```

Let's check if everything is ok :

```
echo %Ant%
%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Downloads\apache-ant-1.9.0-bin\apache-ant-1.9.0\bin

set | findstr Ant
Ant=%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Downloads\apache-ant-1.9.0-bin\apache-ant-1.9.0\bin
```

Everything seems ok :)

To makes it work i had to :

- Escape `%` characters using carets (`^`).
- Remove double quotes.